# HP laptop always on high performance after installing SSD drive

Tags: laptop, ssd, cpu, power-options

I installed a Samsung 850evo SSD drive and it's working fine but the Balanced power plan is missing from the power options. Only Samsung High Performance and HP Recommend power plans are available.

Also, on both plans the CPU clock speed is always 100%, even when the laptop is idle. Due to this, the CPU temp is going up to 65 degrees Celsius. Before installing the drive it was always less than 50 degrees.

Can anyone tell me how to get the Balanced power plan back which reduces the CPU speed when the laptop is idle?

Answer (score 2):

#### Can anyone tell me how to get Balanced power plan back?

**Option 1**

> **Restore the power plans to default**
>
> 1. Click Start, type `cmd` in the Start search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. In the command prompt, type `powercfg –restoredefaultschemes` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 3. Exit command prompt.
>
> Note: This would reset the power plan settings to default. Any
>   customized power plans are would be removed.

Source [Balanced power plan option missing from power options - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/balanced-power-plan-option-missing-from-power/5eebc5c7-e7e2-4c3a-9fda-65c5350386fd)

**Option 2**

> 1. Open a command prompt.
> 2. Copy and paste the command below for the missing power plan you want to restore into the command prompt, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (see
>      screenshot below)
>
> (Power saver)
>
> ```
> powercfg -duplicatescheme a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
> ```
>
> (Balanced)
>
> ```
> powercfg -duplicatescheme 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
> ```
>
> (High Performance)
>
> ```
> powercfg -duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
> ```
>
> (Ultimate Performance - Windows 10 build 17101 and later)
>
> ```
> powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> 3. You can now close the command prompt if you like.

Source [Restore Missing Default Power Plans in Windows 10 | Windows 10 Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/110372-restore-missing-default-power-plans-windows-10-a.html)

**Option 3**

> **Restore Missing Default Power Plan by Importing POW file**
>
> You must be signed in as an administrator to do this option. This
>   option can be handy if Option 2 will not work for you.
>
> 1. Download the [Default_Power_Plans.zip](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/188936d1526483045-restore-missing-default-power-plans-windows-10-a-default_power_plans.zip) file.
> 2. Save the Default_Power_Plans.zip file to your desktop.
> 3. Unblock the Default_Power_Plans.zip file.
> 4. Open the Default_Power_Plans.zip file, and extract (drag and drop) the Balanced.pow, High performance.pow, Power saver.pow, or Ultimate
>      Performance.pow file to your desktop for the missing power plan you
>      want to restore.
>
>    [image: Name: Default_Power_Plans.zip.jpg Views: 1212 Size: 49.1 KB]
> 5. Open an [elevated command prompt](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-open-elevated-command-prompt-windows-10-a.html).
> 6. Type the command below into the elevated command prompt, and press Enter to import the power plan (.pow file). (see screenshot below)
>
>    ```
>    powercfg -import "Full path of .pow file"
>    ```
>
>    Substitute Full path of .pow file in the command above with the actual
>      full path of the .pow file (ex: "Ultimate Performance.pow") file from
>      step 4.
>
>    For example:
>
>    powercfg -import "C:\Users\Brink\Desktop\Ultimate Performance.pow"
>
>    [image: Name: Import_Ultimate_Performace_power_plan.png Views: 1208 Size: 27.6 KB]
> 7. When finished, you can close the elevated command prompt if you like.

Source [Restore Missing Default Power Plans in Windows 10 | Windows 10 Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/110372-restore-missing-default-power-plans-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: i did this restore. and after that only hp recommend and power saver plan shows, balanced plan is still missing..  Also on Hp recommend plan CPU is always on high even on idle laptop..

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: thank you sir.. balanced power plan restored via option 3.. but my CPU clock speed is staying always on 2700Mhz even when laptop is idle and no application running and in task manager CPU usage is less than 20%.. Due to high CPU clock speed processor is heating a lot and fan is working on full speed continuously..   Is it because of SSD installation ?

Comment: No idea :/ ....